# Как использовать метод .lower вместе с .startswith?

Tags: python, python-3.x, методы

Как использовать метод `'str'.lower` вместе с методом `'str'.startswith`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строки в Python неизменяемые (immutable), поэтому все функции/методы которые как-либо изменяют строковые переменные возвращают **новый** измененный объект типа `str`, к которому соответственно можно применить следующий метод:

```
s = "AbA"

if s.lower().startswith("ab"):
    ...
```

Такие конструкции могут быть достаточно длинными:

```
print(" BLAH - BLAH ".strip().lower().capitalize().replace(" ", ""))
# Blah-blah
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод `lower` возвращает сроку, `startswith` возвращает булево значение (`True`/`False`), значит нужно делать так

```
if 'строка'.lower().startswith('x'):
    #какой-то код
```

Если Вы измените порядок, сразу вернётся булево значение, и затем будет попытка привести его к нижнему регистру, что вызовет ошибку.

Выполнение идёт слева направо.